# Unexpected Profile Page on Click - Is this a bug?

Tags: bug, status-declined, community-wiki, users

When I click the "george" (please see the screenshot) on [What are the best ways to increase a site's position in Google?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-are-the-best-ways-to-increase-a-sites-position-in-google) redirect to the following profile page:

https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/23/ilhan

I am expecting to go profile for user name "george". Is it a bug?

[image: Community Wiki post showing the author name "george"]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This user changed their display name on their profile.   What you are seeing is their old user name on the wiki question.

This is a known issue: [Old usernames stick to Community Wiki posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47474/old-usernames-stick-to-community-wiki-posts).  [Jeff Atwood](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1/jeff-atwood) says:

> That's stored in a denormalized field, so it will reflect the username at the time it was last calculated (usually on edit).

To make the most recent user name appear, that question would need to be edited.